# Change image source for all images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some empty image tags on my page with an image stored in a data attribute.

On page load i'd like to take this value from the data attribute and place it in the source...

```
$('div').each('img').attr('src', $(this).data('src'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/09e9bdwd/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not using [`each`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) correctly. Here you have a usage sample

```
$('div img').each(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.attr('src', $this.data('src'));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way to do that:

```
$('div img').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).data('src'));    
});
```

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/09e9bdwd/1/

Answer (score 0):

A slightly speedier approach vs. using `.each()`

```js
var images     = document.querySelectorAll("div img"),
    imageCount = document.images.length;

for (var i = 0; i < imageCount; i++) {
  images[i].setAttribute("src", images[i].dataset.src);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="" data-src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="" data-src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>

<div>
  <img src="" data-src="http://placehold.it/150x150">
</div>
```